# Max value for each object in an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, nspredicate

I have an array of dictionaries that I am trying to get the Max score for each player in the array. Each player can have multiple entries I am trying to get an array of dictionaries of each players best score.

NSArray 
[0] - NSDictionary

```
        - [0] Score: (double)20.7
        - [1] NameID: (int) 1
        - [2] Date
```

[1] - NSDictionary

```
        - [0] Score: (double)25
        - [1] NameID: (int) 1
        - [2] Date
```

[2] - NSDictionary

```
        - [0] Score: (double)28
        - [1] NameID: (int) 2
        - [2] Date
```

[3] - NSDictionary`

```
        - [0] Score: (double)26
        - [1] NameID: (int) 3
        - [2] Date
```

I have tried using NSPredicate predicateWithFormat but I am only able to get back the max for everything in the array not related to the name.

**Expected Output:**

NSArray 
[1] - NSDictionary

```
        - [0] Score: (double)25
        - [1] NameID: (int) 1
        - [2] Date
```

[2] - NSDictionary

```
        - [0] Score: (double)28
        - [1] NameID: (int) 2
        - [2] Date
```

[3] - NSDictionary`

```
        - [0] Score: (double)26
        - [1] NameID: (int) 3
        - [2] Date
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try putting NameID in your NSPredicate? How are you setting your NSPredicate?

Comment: I am not sure how to add the NameID into the predicate and evaluate the max score...  I have tried a lot of different ways including subqueries but I am missing something... I tried this but later found it was totally wrong... NSPredicate *predicate1   = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.Score = NameID.@max.Score"];

Comment: Don't overthink it. Just iterate over the array of dictionaries, building your output dictionary as you go. For each player ID, simply check the score against the one in the output dictionary (if any) and update the output if required

Comment: I was overthinking it. Thought I could make it simple by using NSPredicate but ended up making it way more complex then I needed... Thank you to all for your responses. Some answers below did not work as expected. I marked the one I used as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an `NSPredicate` for this, since you want to determine the maximum score for several different players.  Under the covers, `NSPredicate` iterates the array anyway, so using your own loop isn't any less efficient.  In the following code I have assumed that the scores and player names are wrapped in `NSNumber`

```
-(NSArray *)maxScoresForPlayers:(NSArray *)playerScores {

    NSMutableDictionary *maxScores = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    for (NSDictionary *player in playerScores) {
        NSNumber *playerID = (NSNumber *)player[@"NameID"];
        NSDictionary *playerMax = maxScores[playerID];
        if (playerMax == nil) {
           playerMax = player;
        } else {
           NSNumber *currentMax = (NSNumber *)[playerMax[@"Score"];
           NSNumber *playerScore = (NSNumber *)player[@"Score"];
           if ([playerScore doubleValue] > [currentMax doubleValue]) {
                playerMax = player;
           }
        }
        maxScores[playerID] = playerMax;
    }

    return([maxScores allValues];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *maxScoresDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary *score in scoresArray) {
    NSNumber *key = score[@"NameID"];
    NSNumber *savedMax = maxScoresDict[key][@"Score"];
    NSNumber *currentMax = maxScoresDict[key][@"Score"];
    if (savedMax == nil || [currentMax doubleValue] > [savedMax doubleValue]) {
        maxScoresDict[key] = score;
    }
}
NSArray *maxScoresArray = [maxScoresDict allValues];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *objects = @[@{@"Score": @(20.7),
                       @"NameID": @(1),
                       @"Date": [NSDate date]},
                     @{@"Score": @(25),
                       @"NameID": @(1),
                       @"Date": [NSDate date]},
                     @{@"Score": @(28),
                       @"NameID": @(2),
                       @"Date": [NSDate date]},
                     @{@"Score": @(26),
                       @"NameID": @(3),
                       @"Date": [NSDate date]}];
NSMutableArray *users = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<objects.count; i++) {

    NSDictionary *dict = objects[i];
    NSNumber *nameID = dict[@"NameID"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.NameID==%@", nameID];
    NSInteger index = [users indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        BOOL found = [predicate evaluateWithObject:obj];
        return found;
    }];

    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        NSNumber *score1 = dict[@"Score"];
        NSNumber *score2 = users[index][@"Score"];

        if (score1.doubleValue > score2.doubleValue) {
            [users replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dict];
        }
    }
    else {
        [users addObject:dict];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", users);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSArray *)getBestScores:(NSArray *)players {
    NSMutableDictionary *best = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *p in players) {
        NSDictionary *b = [best valueForKey:[p valueForKey:@"NameID"]];
        if (!b || [[p valueForKey:@"Score"] doubleValue] > [[b valueForKey:@"Score"] doubleValue])
            [best setValue:p forKey:[p valueForKey:@"NameID"]];
    }
    return [best allValues];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get Max Value of integer element from Array of Dictonaries.
// Example Array Starts

<paramArray>(
{
DicID = 1;
Name = "ABC";
ValuetoCalculateMax = 2800;
},
{
DicID = 2;
Name = "DEF";
ValuetoCalculateMax = 2801;
},
{
DicID = 3;
Name = "GHI";
ValuetoCalculateMax = 2805;
}
)
// Example Array Ends

// Implementation


int   MaxintegerValue=0;

MaxintegerValue=[self getMaxValueFromArrayofDictonaries:paramArray];

// Implementation Ends


// Function Starts

-(int)getMaxValueFromArrayofDictonaries:(NSArray *)paramArray
{
int MaxValue=0;
NSMutableDictionary  *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for ( int i=0; i<[paramArray count]; i++ )
{
    dic=[paramArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[dic valueForKey:@"ValuetoCalculateMax"] intValue] > MaxValue)
    {
        MaxValue=[[dic valueForKey:@"ValuetoCalculateMax"] intValue];
    }
    else
    {
        MaxValue=MaxValue;
    }
    }
   return MaxValue;
}

// Function Ends
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is find scores for each user, then find the max score out of it.

```
- (void)findMaxScoreForUser:(int)userId {

NSDictionary *dict0 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@27.0,@3] forKeys:@[@"Score",@"UserID"]];
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@25.0,@2] forKeys:@[@"Score",@"UserID"]];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@23.0,@3] forKeys:@[@"Score",@"UserID"]];

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict0,dict1,dict2, nil];
NSMutableArray *scores = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dict in arr) {
    int userID = [[dict valueForKey:@"UserID"] intValue];
    if (userId == userID) {
        [scores addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Score"]];
    }
}

int max = [[scores valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];

}
```